# Problema ao inserir dados de formulário no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, criei um formulário para cadastro e esse formulário deve enviar via POST sem sair da página e realizar o insert na minha tabela do banco de dados, porém ele entra toda vez no meu "else{echo "Erro, não possível inserir no banco de dados";}"

Realmente não consigo enxergar o motivo de não estar inserindo no banco de dados.
**Código da página**

```
<form class="user-menu-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="POST">
    <nav class="user-menu-form-nav">

        <label class="menu-form-label">Nome:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="Nome" required="required" name="nome_resp" autofocus>
        <br>

        <label class="menu-form-label">CPF ou CNPJ:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ" required="required" name="cpfcnpj_resp">
        <br>
        <label class="menu-form-label">CEP:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="CEP" required="required" id="cep" name="cep_resp" max-length="8">
        <br>
        <label class="menu-form-label">Endereço:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="Endereço" id="rua" required="required" name="endereco_resp">
        <br>

        <label class="menu-form-label">Complemento:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="complemento" id="complemento" required="required" name="complemento_resp">
        <br>
        <label class="menu-form-label">Bairro:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="Bairro" id="bairro" required="required" name="bairro_resp">
        <br>
        <label class="menu-form-label">Cidade:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="Cidade" required="required" id="cidade" name="cidade_resp">
        <br>
        <label  class="menu-form-label">UF:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="UF" required="required" name="uf_resp" id="uf">
        <br>
        <label class="menu-form-label">País:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="País" required="required" name="pais_resp">
        <br>
        <label class="menu-form-label">E-mail:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" name="email_resp">
        <br>
        <label class="menu-form-label">Telefone:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="Telefone" required="required" name="fone_resp">
        <br>
        <label class="menu-form-label">Celular:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="Celular" required="required" name="cel_resp">
        <br><label class="menu-form-label">Tutelado:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="Responsável" required="required" name="responsavel_usuarios1">
        <br>
        <br><label class="menu-form-label">Tutelado:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="Responsável" name="responsavel_usuarios2">
        <br>
        <br><label class="menu-form-label">Tutelado:</label>
        <input class="user-menu-input" type="text" placeholder="Responsável" name="responsavel_usuarios3">
        <br>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="menu-form-btn" type="submit" method="POST"><img src="assets/imgs/check.png" width="12px;">Cadastrar</button>
    <button class="menu-form-btn"><img src="assets/imgs/clipboard.png" width="16px;"><a href="listagem.php">Listagem</a></button>
    <?php
    include 'conecta.php';
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $cpfcnpj_resp        = $_POST['cpfcnpj_resp'];
        $nome_resp           = $_POST['nome_resp'];
        $endereco_resp       = $_POST['endereco_resp'];
        $complemento_resp    = $_POST['complemento_resp'];
        $bairro_resp         = $_POST['bairro_resp'];
        $cep_resp            = $_POST['cep_resp'];
        $cidade_resp         = $_POST['cidade_resp'];
        $uf_resp             = $_POST['uf_resp'];
        $pais_resp           = $_POST['pais_resp'];
        $email_resp          = $_POST['email_resp'];
        $fone_resp           = $_POST['fone_resp'];
        $cel_resp            = $_POST['cel_resp'];
        $responsavel_usuarios1   = $_POST['responsavel_usuarios1'];
        $responsavel_usuarios2   = $_POST['responsavel_usuarios2'];
        $responsavel_usuarios3   = $_POST['responsavel_usuarios3'];

        $sql  = "INSERT INTO responsavel (cpf_cnpj_resp,nome_resp,endereco_resp,complemento_resp,bairro_resp,cep_resp,cidade_resp,uf_resp,pais_resp,email_resp,fone_resp,cel_resp,hospede_1_resp_cpf,hospede_2_resp_cpf,hospede_3_resp_cpf) VALUES ('$cpfcnpj_resp','$nome_resp','$endereco_resp','$complemento_resp','$bairro_resp','$cep_resp','$cidade_resp','$uf_resp','$pais_resp','$email_resp','$fone_resp','$cel_resp','$responsavel_usuarios1','$responsavel_usuarios2','$responsavel_usuarios3')";
        mysqli_query($conecta,$sql); //Realiza a consulta
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($conecta) == 1){
            echo "<h4> gravado com sucesso</h4>";
            sleep(2);
        } else {
            echo "Erro, não possível inserir no banco de dados";
        }
        mysqli_close($conecta); //fecha conexão com banco de dados
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

**conecta.php**

```
<?php
$conecta = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
// Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
mysqli_select_db($conecta, 'car0000001') or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
mysqli_set_charset($conecta, 'utf8');
?>
```

Comment: $conecta = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or trigger_error(mysql_error()); --> Aqui falta o " i " em mysql_error().
E no seu if pra verificar se foi alterado com sucesso, acho que seria melhor ao inves de verificar se é igual a um, verificar se é !=0 . Talvez ajude

Comment: Vitor, fiz o que você falou, ele saiu do meu else e entrou no IF porém NADA foi registrado no banco de dados...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se o valor da variavel sql esta correto, debugge e  execute o comando diretamente no banco e veja se esta sendo inserido.